# jQuery Simulate onkeydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

I got a question regarding the package [Simulate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate/) which enables to really simulate an event. I need this library to simulate real events for my unit test.

But I am wondering. Is there a way to give extra parameters to my simulate call so that I can simulate a keypress?

Code I have so far:

```
$("#id1").simulate('keydown');
```

But I need something like:

```
$("#id3").simulate('keydown',keyCode='13');
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You can take a look here: https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without Simulate:**

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // # Some key code value
$("#id3").trigger(e);
```

---

**Simulate:**

In https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js you can find:

```
$.fn.simulate = function( type, options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        new $.simulate( this, type, options );
    });
};
```

There is this **options** stuff that means options are availble, which ones ?

Look to the doc', to learn about options. If you dont find the option you need, you should hack Simulate or not use it.

Comment: I could not find any doc from the [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate) page and there is no independent website. Also the note that the author says : "jquery-simulate is in use by projects of the jQuery Foundation, but **isn't under active development**. [...]. We hesitate to put more time into this project, since **its future is unclear**". So I would think twice before using this.

Comment: The lattest update in GitHub was 6months ago... it isnt under development nor support, and finally... trigger do the job. You should forget `jquery-simulate`. Bye bye Simulate.

Comment: Based on the documentation indeed I found the following solution: `$("#id1").simulate('keydown',{keyCode: 13}); ` Thanks @Strukt